# How to position a wrappable label in boxlayout --kivy

Tags: python, kivy, label, textinput

I have a hard time thinking about a markup TextField in kivymd/kivy. As u know their is know markup available in any textfield/textinput ,the next idea crossed my mind was creating a textfield like of that stackoverflow. Meaning their will be a textfield and below will be a label and the label's text will keep  modifying as we go on writing on the textfield.
The idea seems to be working but have few problems

1. The positioning of label (left-right) is difficult in kivy.
   2.I don't know why but the label below will slowly rise up in the boxlayout and will eventually collide or overlap will the above textfield. (I want u too run the below code and check by writing minimum 12 lines. u can see the label overlapping the textfield)

i want help in this problems..

The label has `size_hint_y` set to **None**,and has a `text_size` set to `200,None`

the sample code is below

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder

str = """

MDCard:
    pos_hint : {'x':0.056 , 'top':0.836}
    size_hint : 0.88,0.82

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x : False
        BoxLayout:
            height : self.minimum_height
            orientation : 'vertical'
            size_hint : 1,None
            spacing : 15
            padding : 55

            MDTextField:
                id : input_field_1
                mode : 'rectangle'
                size_hint : 0.4,None
                #pos_hint : {'x' : 0.1,'top': 0.8}
                hint_text : '    '
                #y_scroll : True
                multiline : True
                
            Label:
                text : input_field_1.text
                color : 0,0,0,1
                text_size : 200,None
                size_hint_y : None
                #height : self.minimum_height
                maximum_lines : 2
        
                
"""
class My_4app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(str)
My_4app().run()
```

Any help in this matter is very very much appreciated. And can i know is it possible that we can add a label in a textfield such that it's text go along with the textfields text..

plz if possible reply fast and lemma know if u want any more info

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `self.minimum_height` for a `BoxLayout`, you must ensure that the heights of its children are well defined. So, you cannot use `size_hint_y` for the children of the `BoxLayout`. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that I think will do what you want:

```
MDCard:
    pos_hint : {'x':0.056 , 'top':0.836}
    size_hint : 0.88,0.82

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x : False
        BoxLayout:
            height : self.minimum_height
            orientation : 'vertical'
            size_hint : 1,None
            spacing : 15
            padding : 55

            MDTextField:
                id : input_field_1
                mode : 'rectangle'
                size_hint : 0.4,None
                height: max(44, self.minimum_height)
                hint_text : '    '
                multiline : True
                
            Label:
                text : input_field_1.text
                color : 0,0,0,1
                text_size : 200,None
                size_hint_y : None
                height: max(44, self.texture_size[1])
```

The main changes are setting `size_hint_y` to `None` for both of the children of the `BoxLayout`, and setting a value for the `height` of each.